# simulate over for loop and save values in vector

Tags: r

This output gives me 70 values of `s`. I want the values saved in a vector but this code doesnt work. (It gives me only the 7 values of the last run from the j-loop). I need help thanks.

```
a<-c(-2,3,44,2,455,6,5) 
v<-numeric()
for(i in 1:7){
    for(j in 1:10){
        s<-rnorm(1,0,1)+a[i]
        print(s) 
    }
}

a<-c(-2,3,44,2,455,6,5) 
v<-numeric()
for(i in 1:7){
    for(j in 1:10){
        s<-rnorm(1,0,1)+a[i]
        v[j]<-s 
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy: `replicate(10, rnorm(7) + a)`. That's it. Then you can make a vector out of it, if you want to.

Comment: sorry i need this with two for loops because its only an example of a bigger code

Answer (score 0):

The following code will produce a 7x10 matrix with the vectors the question asks for.

```
a <- c(-2, 3, 44, 2, 455, 6, 5)

set.seed(1234)
v <- numeric(7)
mat <- matrix(nrow = 7, ncol = 10)
for(i in 1:7){
  for(j in 1:10){
    s <- rnorm(1, 0, 1) + a[i]
    v[j] <- s 
  }
  mat[i, ] <- v
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun, more `R` like:

```
sapply(a,function(i){
  unlist(lapply(1:10,function(j){
    rnorm(1, 0, 1)+i
  }))
})           


[,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]
 [1,] -3.295962 3.577820 44.41137 2.001589 454.9179 5.970766 5.603785
 [2,] -2.571828 2.259008 43.73227 2.643309 455.1282 5.997461 5.653614
 [3,] -2.084684 2.822167 42.13170 3.650840 455.7986 6.904609 4.438424
 [4,] -2.079247 4.085084 43.45838 1.502186 453.7527 5.436269 7.839745
 [5,] -2.476034 3.030010 44.50353 2.976790 454.0916 6.599311 6.996301
 [6,] -1.902021 3.215603 45.15090 1.295879 455.5759 6.817221 5.841700
 [7,] -2.743911 3.224363 44.83895 2.069357 454.2933 7.585631 5.460610
 [8,] -3.285025 3.414776 44.89513 5.128345 454.7776 6.267330 5.156807
 [9,] -3.303973 3.756869 42.94848 1.590817 456.0266 5.303505 4.445430
[10,] -2.900838 1.912637 44.86769 3.227049 454.3163 5.434879 7.545130
```

doesn't recquire you to define the empty matrix